# Space Cadets with Secret Android rumor

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story probably anthologized in a golden age collection about space cadets that are under the impression they have to figure out who in their class is the secret android (and maybe kill him). They end up picking the valedictorian / smartest in the class for obvious reasons.

I think that it might then be revealed that this is a hoax played upon the students by the instructors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are seeking the 1974 short story [Pacer](http://www.classzone.com/novelguides/litcons/witch/related.cfm) by Raymond F. Jones (not to be confused with [his 1943 story](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46715) with the same title).

Pacer by Raymond F. Jones
(from [*Future Kin*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?14882), © 1974)
Summary: A class of futuristic space cadets must decide whether to accept a member whom they suspect to be a robot known as the Pacer or to follow tradition and kill him.

Comment: @user14111. Thanks for catching the typo.  I had it listed as Pacer in the longer description. Accidently added 'The' in the link description.  Very interesting to hear about the other Pacer story. I have only ever read the first one.